# Split the string by a regular expression on the part (Scala language)

Tags: regex, scala

How to split a string into three parts by a regular expression:

The first part contains the prefix the match;

The second part contains a match for the regular expression;

The third part contains the postfix the match.

```
val line="before word after word tree"
val regex="""word""".r

val (resultLeft,result,resultRight) = find(line, regex) //("before ","word"," after word tree")
```

I need to describe "find" on Scala language

Comment: What are you asking? Where's your attempt?

Comment: I want to get the equivalent of Perl variables $` $& $'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution

```
def find(line:String,regex: String)={
    val matcher=regex.r.pattern.matcher(line)
    if (matcher.find()){
        (
            line.substring(0,matcher.start()),
            line.substring(matcher.start(),matcher.end()),
            line.substring(matcher.end())
        )
    }else
        throw new Exception("no match")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can group regexes by parantheses.**

Then, you can reach them through matchings with `regex.findAllIn`.

```scala
object Main extends App {
    val str   = "prefix:somestring:postfix";
    val regex = """(prefix:)([A-z0-9]+)(:postfix)""".r

    regex.findAllIn(str).matchData foreach {
       m => System.out.println(m.group(1), m.group(2), m.group(3))
    }
}
```